# O que é um Conteúdo Misto? E quais são os "Conteúdo opcionalmente bloqueável" e "Conteúdo bloqueável"?

Tags: html, segurança, servidor, http-request, ssl

Apesar de não entender quase nada sobre esse assunto eu estava lendo sobre os Protocolos e Certificados de segurança, pois vi esse alerta de `Mixed Content` em um site

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lendo sobre o assunto me deparei com termos como "Conteúdo Misto", "Conteúdo opcionalmente bloqueável" e "Conteúdo bloqueável" e fiquei me perguntando o que seriam eles...

- O que define um documento como sendo de "Conteúdo Misto"?
- Quais são os "**Conteúdo opcionalmente bloqueável**" e se são opcionais como eu defino que são permitidos ou devem ser bloqueados?
- E quais são os "**Conteúdo bloqueável**"?

➽ Minha intenção é saber o que eu posso ou não posso indexar no meu site como `CDNs`, `imagens` externas, etc, e saber se eles são "**Conteúdo opcionalmente bloqueável**" e como defino se no meu site eles são permitidos ou não.